# Selenium Execute JavaScript Exception in IE9

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, selenium

I fight with selenium using Internet Explorer 9 and executing JavaScript. Certain `JavaScripts` work like
`return argument[0].innerHTML or return argument[0].children[0].innerHTML`. If I use `executeScript("return argument[0].childNodes.length;", getElement())` 
or 
`List<WebElement> children = executeScript("return argument[0].children;", getElement())` it fails with a JavaScript error inside IE.

Can someone point me to the problem and why this is happening?

Comment: What's the reason for using JS in the first place?

Comment: We have a SAP toolkit to test and there is a special combobox implemetation. This implementation uses a custom tag to hide some information if they are not visible. Using JavaScript we can see and use this tag without it Selenium can not find it since IE seams to prevent finding and using those tags. Also the tag is hidden.

Comment: OK, what's the error that is reported? What happens if you run that JS in IE's Developer Console? (Replacing the `arguments[0]` with a call to `document.getElement.....etc...`)